# SSL Certificate error on Facebook Android App Only

Tags: android, facebook, ssl, heroku

I'm using Gandi SSL certificate on my subdomain and it's working just fine except when website is accessed through Facebook Android app where I get a security error.

I've doubled checked with [SSLShoper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://tickets.shotguntheapp.com/events/5569) and [QUALYS SSL LABS](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=tickets.shotguntheapp.com&latest), with no issue with the chain reported.

Website URL is `https://tickets.shotguntheapp.com/events/5569` and it can be accessed through Facebook by clicking "Tickets available" [here](https://www.facebook.com/events/884560168242877/permalink/889478237751070/)

Any clue where the issue could come from?

*******Solved issues******

1. First issue was a missing certificate in the chain as Anand
   explained it very well
2. Second issue was in my Heroku `certs:update` command. If you run `heroku certs`, you might see two certificates, of type SNI and Endpoint. **Both have to be updated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Certification Paths section of SSL Labs, you will see that there are two trust paths.

[image: SSL Labs report]

While you are sending an intermediate certificate that extablishes trust for the first path, that particular root (`Gandi Standard SSL CA 2 -- SHA1: 2b8f1b57330dbba2d07a6c51f70ee90ddab9ad8e`) was [only added in Android 5.1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54479). You haven't specified the version of Android you're seeing this error on and I'm assuming it is something before 5.1.

You will need to send another intermediate cert (`USERTrust RSA Certification Authority -- SHA1: eab040689a0d805b5d6fd654fc168cff00b78be3`) to complete the second certification path. You can obtain the correct set of both intermediate chains, in the right order, from [What's My Chain Cert?](https://whatsmychaincert.com/?tickets.shotguntheapp.com)

Comment: Hey Anand, thanks for the quick reply, you're right but now I'm trying to find out how to send this another intermediate cert. I tried to concatenate the three certificates :

'cat tickets.shotguntheapp.com.crt GandiStandardSSLCA2.crt USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt > STAR_tickets.shotguntheapp.com.crt'

and then 'heroku certs:update STAR_tickets.shotguntheapp.com.crt tickets.shotguntheapp.com.key' but the USERTrust certificate is still missing. Do you know what's wrong in my chain creation?

Comment: That seems to be correct. The one downloaded from What's My Chain Cert? has the two intermediate certs in this order - Gandi Standard SSL CA 2, USERTrust RSA Certification Authority. Can you try using the `--bypass` flag when running `certs:update` as indicated here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#update-certificate

Comment: I've also tried to concatenate directly my server certificate with one downloaded from What's My Chain Cert? `cat tickets.shotguntheapp.com.crt tickets.shotguntheapp.com.chain.crt > tickets.shotguntheapp.com.chained.crt` and ran this time `heroku certs:update tickets.shotguntheapp.com.chained.crt tickets.shotguntheapp.com.key --bypass`, but What's My Chain Cert still gives me a warning

Comment: maybe is there some latence in the SSL certs:update? or should I include the root cert as well?

Comment: Adding the root certificate isn't required. I'm sorry but I do not know enough about Heroku to help you out here.

Comment: Hi, so the issue was with Heroku multiple certs, I add to update both SNI and Endpoint certificates... Anyway, you helped through the first part of the problem thank you very much!

Comment: Just one more thing: web page look now unreachable through Facebook Android app after certificate update, any idea why?